# How do I configure device nodes for simple-pm-bus probe?

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, device-tree

Inside a soc node I have a watchdog node with a simple-mdf device.

```
soc {
        #address-cells = <2>;
        #size-cells = <2>;
        compatible = "simple-bus";
        ranges;
        toprgu: watchdog@10007000 {
            compatible = "mediatek,mt6589-wdt", "syscon", "simple-mfd";
            reg = <0 0x10017000 0 0x1000>;
            ...
            reboot-mode {
                compatible = "syscon-reboot-mode";
            };
        };
};
```

My problem is that when probing I get the following result

```
[    0.105509] bus: 'platform': add driver simple-pm-bus
[    0.105555] bus: 'platform': __driver_probe_device: matched device soc with driver simple-pm-bus
[    0.105574] bus: 'platform': really_probe: probing driver simple-pm-bus with device soc
[    0.105630] driver: 'simple-pm-bus': driver_bound: bound to device 'soc'
[    0.105811] bus: 'platform': really_probe: bound device soc to driver simple-pm-bus
[    0.105832] bus: 'platform': __driver_probe_device: matched device 10007000.watchdog with driver simple-pm-bus
[    0.105846] bus: 'platform': really_probe: probing driver simple-pm-bus with device 10007000.watchdog
[    0.105891] simple-pm-bus: probe of 10007000.watchdog rejects match -19
```

The simple-pm-bus driver seems to reject devices with `compatible = "foo", "syscon", "simple-mfd"` in my tree. The **mt6589-wdt** (foo) probes ok and even reports

```
mtk-wdt 10007000.watchdog: Watchdog enabled (timeout=10 sec, nowayout=0)
```

What puzzles me is why simple-pm-bus rejects the device? Are the any special properties that I am missing?